# Keyboard not working after installing Windows 8

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, keyboard, login

I had Ubuntu on my Computer. I then installed Windows 8, after which I could not boot from Ubuntu. So I installed GRUB using Boot-repair from a Live USB.

Now, when I boot and see GRUB, I can use my keyboard to change the options using the arrows. After selecting Ubuntu, I am presented with 3 options-My login, Guest Login, and Remote Login. If I select Guest login, everything works just fine. But if I select MY LOGIN, the I am not even able to enter my password using the keyboard. Using the virtual keyboard, I logged into my account. But after that also, I am not able to use my keyboard.

I tried turning ACPI off in the GRUB, but it isn't working. My boot repair link is http://paste.ubuntu.com/7233665/

Comment: Can you please post your dmesg output

Answer (score 0):

The USB keyboard is not being seen by the system, Change it to a serial keyboard till it boots then after password, install the USB keyboard. Remember you can hook up a USB with the system running.